# Basis of homomorpshims of abelian varieties with minimal degree

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $A, B$ be simple abelian varieties of dimension $g$ defined over a finite field $k$. We know that $Hom_k(A, B)$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of dimension $2g$.

Is it always possible to have a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis $f_1,...f_{2g}$ of $Hom_k(A, B)$ such that for all $f \in Hom_k(A, B)$
$$
\deg f \geq \deg f_i \quad i=1,...,2g
$$
?

Comment: Firstly, it is not true that ${\rm dim}{\rm Hom}_k(A,B)$ always has rank $2g$, rather it has rank at least $2g$ (and at most $(2g)^2$). For example the endomorphism ring of a supersingular elliptic curve is an order in a quaternion algebra. And secondly, for a basis as you demand to exist, all $f_i$ would have to have the same (minimal) degree, which is clearly not always possible. If, for example, $E$ is an ordinary elliptic curve with CM by $K$, then the only way you can have a basis for ${\rm End} E$ with both elements of degree $1$ is if $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: Thank you @AlexB., can you explain why if both elements are of degree $1$ then the only possibility is $K=Q(i)$?